# can map key and value could be from derived class

Tags: c++, generics, stdmap

I want to build data structure, incapsulating map , but not template!

```
struct mananager
{
    map<KeyClass, ValueClass> myMap;
}

class KeyClass
{
  //
}
class ValueClass
{
  //
}

class derivedKeyClass : public KeyClass
{
  //
}

class derivedValueClass : public ValueClass
{
 //
}
 manager m;
 derivedKeyClass dkey;
 derivedValueClass  dValue;
 m.myMap[dkey] = dValue;
```

Is it correct? Or should use pointer and can`t change a type for key  `map<KeyClass, ValueClass*> myMap;`

Comment: Both `dkey` and `dValue` are _sliced_ in `m.myMap[dkey] = dValue;`. Changing the value type of the map to a pointer won't entirely fix that.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - what is sliced? if I use always same kye type. and a pointer for a value - could it work?

Comment: @Yakov - question: if always using same key type, why create ``derivedKeyClass``?

Comment: @trozzel - now it is always int. but i want to make this class maximum possible generic. Thus i wanted a key also to be generic. if not possible int key is also ok

Comment: @Yakov That is what templates are for!

Comment: @Yakov "*what is sliced?*" - if something is declared as `KeyClass` and you assign it a `derivedKeyClass`, [slicing occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Same with `ValueClass` and `derivedValueClass`. Polymorphism only works with pointers and references, and you can't use either of those for a map's `key_type` (well, not easily, anyway), but you can use a `ValueClass*` pointer for its `mapped_type`, eg: `map<KeyClass, ValueClass*> m; KeyClass key; derivedValueClass dValue; m[key] = &dValue;`